# Breeze empty data when calling executeLocally

Tags: angularjs, node.js, breeze

Am using a node restful server that sends simple data in this form:

```
[{id:1, note:"blah blah"}]
```

I followed the examples of **no-server**, were one uses a JsonResultsAdapter and the other one uses MetadataHelper, tried both ways and they failed to work. I used bower to install the libraries:

*"breeze-client": "^1.5.6" and "breeze-client-labs": "^1.5.8",*

I followed the tutorial of [Debugging query result](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/query-debugging.html)  and passed the whole test, but nothing breeze would not materialize the data after downloading it of the server. 
Some code:

```
var serviceRoot = window.location.protocol+ '//' + window.location.host + '/';
this.serviceName = serviceRoot + 'api/';
this.defaultNamespace = 'models';

var ds = new breeze.DataService({
            serviceName: this.serviceName,
            hasServerMetadata: false
        });

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({dataService : ds});
var meta = manager.metadataStore;

var DT = breeze.DataType;
var keyGen = breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity;

this.helper = new breeze.config.MetadataHelper(this.defaultNamespace, keyGen);
this.helper.addDataService(meta, serviceName);

var entityType = {
            name: lookups,
            autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.None,
            dataProperties: {
                id: {type: DT.Int32},
                note: {maxLength: 50, isNullable: false}
            }
        };

this.helper.addTypeToStore(meta, entityType);
```

Calling the server, I see the network traffic with the json payload and then breeze applies the entityAspect to the data and associates the EntityType with it  when using this query.

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('users/lookups')
            .using(this.manager).execute()
            .then(this.querySucceeded)
            .catch(this.queryFailed);
```

now when i call to get the cashed data i get nothing an empty array using this query:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('Lookups)
            .using(this.manager)
            .executeLocally();
```

I am at a lost and cant see why its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it to work by adding the property of defaultResourceName to the entityType definition

```
var entityType = {
        name: 'Lookup',
        defaultResourceName: 'users/lookups' ,
        autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.None,
        dataProperties: {
            id: {type: DT.Int32},
            note: {maxLength: 50, isNullable: false}
        }
    };
```

and also i called the query using 'Lookup' not in plural form

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('Lookup)
        .using(this.manager)
        .executeLocally();
```